# Best managed postgres service that can scale in size

Tags: database, postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently building a data intensive web service and I'm struggling to identify the best managed database provider for my need.

**In short:**

- I currently have a database that has 3gb of data.
- My database will grow by 6 to 30gb every month up to 1tb (next month 10gb, following month: 30gb, etc)
- All my data is constantly being updated so it's not like I'm saving stuff to only use it in read-only mode

Right now I'm using a 10gb managed postgres db on DigitalOcean but I will soon need to migrate my db to a bigger instance (I plan on doing it when I'll reach 8gb of storage in a couple of weeks).

**The issue is that I both:**

- Don't want to have to migrate my database every month for a bigger instance
- Don't want to reserve a 500gb database knowing that 80% of it won't be used within the next 6 months. This is not cost effective

I looked at Google Cloud Big Query which seem to scale without needing to migrate databases but I fear that it might end up costing a ton because:

- I constantly refresh/update my data in my tables
- My queries perform lookups on my tables which can take some time and might be resource intensive (so far my queries are always smaller than 3sec)

It's the first time I'm managing large project like this and I'm not sure about what is the best solution.

Would you have insights?

Comment: Do you need to update your database very frequently? Is it like an operational database?

Comment: Yes I do.
I have crawlers that constantly look at the database and compare its content with what they found online.

Comment: Great. And what about your data model? Is it a relational model?

Comment: Yes relational model.
Other details (I have 7 tables). My 2 biggest table (and the ones that get most of the processing are:
- Table 1: 1M rows and 16 columns
- Table 2: 3M rows and 7 columns (6 are Int and 1 is Json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relational model and need to update your database very frequently, you probably should not use `BigQuery`. BigQuery is an excellent option if your purpose is analysis (i.e., few updates and complex queries), but it's not built to be used as a DBMS.

In your case, if you want to put your project on `GCP` and also keep your data model as similar as possible with the model you already have, I would suggest you to take a look at [Cloud SQL](http://cloud.google.com/sql) and [Cloud Spanner](http://cloud.google.com/spanner).

Both are fully managed Relational Databases. The main difference is that `Cloud Spanner` is horizontally scalable whereas `Cloud SQL` is not, i.e. if you need only one node, use `Cloud SQL`. If you need to grow up your cluster, use `Cloud Spanner`.

Furthermore, both of them have it's respective Web APIs. You can find the Cloud Spanner Web API reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/). For the Cloud SQL, the reference depends on which DBMS you choose: [SQLServer](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/apis), [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/apis) or [PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/apis).

I hope it helps

Comment: For the use case you describe, your best option would be to use Cloud SQL with PostgreSQL. There is a feature for having your disk scale automatically so that you can start with the 30 Gb you are currently using, and the max storage offered is 1Tb.

I wouldn't recommend using Spanner because that seems like an overkill for your use case.

Comment: Yes that works great. 
Thanks to both of you.